DevExpress Grid Cell Value - using vb.net
How do I get the total number of Credits in Grid2 from each Student ID in Grid1 using VB.Net?
For example: The student ID 99 in Grid2 should have 9 in the "TotalCredits" column.
Grid1
Student ID  CourseNumber      Credit      Description
99                         1                      4        Desc99
99                         8                      1        Desc99
99                         5                      4        Desc99
88                         2                      3        Desc88
88                         9                      3        Desc88
77                         7                      4        Desc77
88     9   3    Desc88
77     7   4    Desc77
Grid2
Student ID   TotalCredits
99             ???
88             ???
77             ???
Code:
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text
Partial Public Class Form1
Public Sub New()
InitializeComponent()
    ' This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
    ' Fill the ExcelDataSource asynchronously
    ExcelDataSource1.FillAsync()
    ' This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
    ' Fill the ExcelDataSource asynchronously
    ExcelDataSource2.FillAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub

End Class

Updated the original post with complete code for the application...
